# iOS: call method from a separate viewController

Tags: ios

In my main view controller, I have a button that calls a popover. Since the popover has it's own view controller, its buttons call methods in the popover's view controller. But how would I call a method from the main view controller?

I tried this. In the popover view controller I added a property in the .h

```
@class ViewController;

@interface PopoverContent : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *parentView;
```

In my popover implementation I did this in viewDidLoad:

```
self.parentView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

In ViewController I have a method called generateHash so I tried

```
[parentView generateHash];
```

But I get the error:

```
No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares selector 'generateHash'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line, don't want to create a new instance of view controller

```
self.parentView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

change this line

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *parentView;
```

to this, so your parent view pointer is of the right class type

```
@property (weak) ParentView *parentView;
```

now inside parent views .m file

```
- (void) createPopup
{
    PopoverView *popoverV = [[PopoverView alloc] init];
    popoverV.parentView = self;

    //And some command to show your popup, addSubview, or presentModal, or whatever
}
```

Then in PopoverView.m file, you can call methods of the parentView like so

```
[self.parentView SomeMethod];
```

Comment: If you use this approach, the reference to `parentView` should be weak.  If it's strong, you'll probably end up with a strong reference cycle and the objects will never be deallocated under ARC.  (Yes, I realize it depends on wether the parent has a strong reference to the "child" PopoverContent instance--it probably does now, or very possibly will as the code is revised in the future.)

Comment: I'm a little confused, I noticed that when I declare the buttons in the popover view controller, for target I can add `self.parentViewController` but none of the methods get called. Seems like that is the simplest way (but it doesn't seem to work)

Comment: like Mike M aid, are your methods declared in header? Any methods in class 1 that are called from class 2 need to be declared in the .h file of class 1, else class 2 can't 'see' them.

Comment: Actually one more question, I've gotten this to work:
`[self.parentView saveImage];`
So should this work? It doesn't...
`[self.buttonSave addTarget:self.parentView action:@selector(saveImage) forControlEvent....];`

Comment: seems like it should if saveImage is defined as "- (void) saveImage{...}", but if its defined as "- (IBAction) saveImage: (id) sender{...}" you'll need to add a colon, like this ....action:@selector(saveImage:).....

Comment: is your control event UIControlEventTouchUpInside?

Comment: It is `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and it is defined in the .h as `-(void)saveImage;`

Comment: is the button in IB set to reference outlet 'buttonSave'?  If it is you could aways break this down into 2 steps for testing.  Have the button action trigger a function call in popover view .m file and then that function can call 'saveImage' in parent view.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use a delegate protocol.  In the PopoverContent.h, add something like this:

```
@protocol PopoverContentDelegate : NSObject
    - (void) method1;
@end
```

Naturally, you can have more than one method, and the method(s) can return values and take parameters like any other method.  Also, in the same file, add property called `delegate`.  (Technically, it can be called anything, but everyone who looks at your code will know exactly what you're doing if you call it delegate.)

```
@interface PopoverContent

@property (weak) id<PopoverContentDelegate > delegate;
//other properties and methods
@end
```

Finally, in your "main" view controller's .m file, import PopoverContent.h file and set the delegate to self.  Also implement method1 to do whatever you need it to do.

```
//Create the view controller
myPopoverContentController.delegate = self;
//Create the popover with the view controller.
```

Now, in PopoverContent controller, you can call method1 on the delegate wherever you need to.

```
[delegate method1];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question, you probably have to define the generateHash method in your ViewController.h file.

Second, I'd suggest that your design approach is not optimal.  The generateHash method probably needs to be in another file that can be called from both your ViewController and Popover content controller.  For example consider another objective-c .h/.m pair "MyHashMethods":

```
    MyHashMethods.h

    + (void)generateHash;
```

---

```
    MyHashMethods.m

    + (void) generateHash
    {
         // hash code
    }
```

This would allow you to just include MyHashMethods.h in whatever view controllers you need and then call

```
    [MyHashMethods generateHash];
```

when you need it.