# Problems presenting a view from a Xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a logout button on my TableView Controller. When I hit it it runs the following code, and it works fine. It changes your login status to 0 (in code not shown) and then moves you to the login screen.

```
- (void)moveToLogInPage {

    // PUSH THE VIEW TO LOGIN PAGE VIEW CONTROLLER

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:Nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginPage"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

But what I want to do, is move the login button from the TableView Controller into a Xib that I have sliding in from the side. The slider is set with the following code and also works fine.

```
 sliderView = [SettingsSlideView createView];
 [self.view addSubview:sliderView];
```

I am just having trouble wrapping my head around how to call the 'moveToLogInPage' function from the sliderView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what Mundi was referring to, but I was able to solve my problem with this question.

[iOS: call method from a separate viewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163837/ios-call-method-from-a-separate-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You should not call any "move to other controller" method from a view. That should be done by the controller. Just keep a reference to the view in the controller and move to the other controller from there.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I get that I shouldn't call it from the view, but could you go into a little more detail?